# Update People picker column using JSON formatting SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, person-or-group

Can we update people picker field in SharePoint using JSON formatting?

I want to update field with current user name.

Comment: Is this single selection field or multiple selections are allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft recently introduced `setValue` custom row action using which you can set the column value from JSON Formatting.

Example: updating multiple selection person or group field:

```
"customRowAction": {
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
        "MultiPersonColumnInteranalName": "=if(indexOf(@currentField.email , @me) > -1 , removeFrom(@currentField.email , @me) , appendTo(@currentField.email , @me) )"
    }
}
```

**Documentation**: [Set multiple field values of an Item using customRowAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced#set-multiple-field-values-of-an-item-using-customrowaction)

---

**Update from comments**:

You can set single selection person or group column simply like this:

```
"customRowAction": {
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
        "PersonColumnInteranalName": "@me"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks how it can be write for single people picker

Comment: check updated answer for single selection person or group column.